# How to have cells save text data from UITextView individually?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have been wondering how to have cells save text data from UITextView individually, using CoreData. Do I need to segue or do something like that? I have no idea... Hopeless with my code skills.

Update:

This is MyMainViewController

```
let ENTITY_NAME = "Tasks"
let ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "desc"


let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchedResultController = getFetchedResultController()
    fetchedResultController.delegate = self
    fetchedResultController.performFetch(nil)
}


// MARK:- PrepareForSegue

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "edit" {
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        let taskController: myViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! myViewController
        let task: Tasks = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Tasks
        taskController.task = task
    }
}

// MARK:- Retrieve Tasks

func getFetchedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
    fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return fetchedResultController
}

func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: ENTITY_NAME)
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}

// MARK: - TableView data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let numberOfSections = fetchedResultController.sections?.count
    return numberOfSections!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let numberOfRowsInSection = fetchedResultController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
    return numberOfRowsInSection!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: AnyObject = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let task = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Tasks
    cell.textLabel?!.text = task.desc.capitalizedString
    return cell as! UITableViewCell
}
```

And I have another ViewController where a UITextView is only set, but I do not know how to have each cell have each different text data. Where and what code do I have to write?

Comment: Welcome to SO. That question is sadly far too broad. You need to be more specific, include some screenshots, your current code, etc. If you want the cells to do something you simply have to code it - there is nothing preventing you from doing so. It might not be a good idea from the software design point of view but it certainly is possible.

Comment: Could you describe more about your situation?

Comment: I just want each cell to store each text. It is like the Note app which is already preinstalled in iPhone. I want to make something like that. Could you provide me with a code example if possible? That's hugely helpful.

Comment: Look into the Model-View-Controller concept (& maybe start w/o CoreData, which has a learning curve). Don't think of cells themselves as "saving" the data - they don't (well, not for longer than they're on screen). The tableView cells & UITextView ("Views") are just dumb boxes that are told by their "Controller" which data to display. That data is stored in a separate "Model," or data source (CoreData in this case). The Controller gets & passes the data to display, and also listens to what the Views tell it ("Hey, My value changed!") to capture new input which it then stores in the Model.

Comment: @mc01 Ahh! I did not know how MVC works. I thought each cell can store each data. But... still, I don't know what kind of code to add to make it happen. I have no idea. It is greatly appreciated if you teach me.